# Looking for a more concise way of writing a relatively common loop?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran77

Is there a more concise way of writing this relatively common type of loop,

```
70  M=NTOC-N
    L=0
    DO 100 I=M,NTOC
    L=L+1
    X(L)=XI(I)
100 Y(L)=YI(I)
```

Without going into definitions of indexes, what it does is it copies the contents of arrays XI, YI from index *M* to *NTOC* to arrays X, Y indexes 1 to ... (NTOC-M) ... how many is needed.

While restructuring some older code, I noticed I had a large number of this kind of loops, and while I probably didn't know better at the time, I was wondering ***is there now a more concise way of writing this to aide code legibility / readability?*** While depending a lot on loops, I know Fortran nowadays has excellent support for all kinds of array operations, so if someone knows a way which they believe could be more legible, I would be very grateful on all suggestions!

Comment: You mean like `x(1:n+1)=xi(ntoc-n:ntoc)`?

Comment: @francescalus - Exactly that. Much appreciated.
If you put it down as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `n` is positive, over the course of the loop `i` takes the values `m`, `m+1`, ..., `ntoc` and so the elements of `xi` chosen are, in order, `xi(m)`, `xi(m+1)`, ..., `xi(ntoc)`.  The elements of `yi` are similar.

In terms of an array section, `xi(m:ntoc)` represents the same selection of elements.

Similarly, the elements of `x` on the left-hand side are `x(1)`, `x(2)`, ..., `x(ntoc-m+1)` (=`x(n+1)`).  As an array section, `x(1:n+1)` represents the same elements.

That means:

```
x(1:n+1)=xi(ntoc-n:ntoc)   ! Replacing m with its value
y(1:n+1)=yi(ntoc-n:ntoc)
```

And if the bounds are `x` and `y` are `1` and `n+1`, or the arrays are allocatable, then the whole arrays `x` and `y` could be used on the left-hand sides.

For `n` zero or negative the array section will safely select the same elements as the loop (one or none).

If you're going to use `i` and `l` outside that fragment then you'll of course have to set those manually (and don't forgot that `i` will take the value `ntoc+1`).

Finally, if you want more incentive to get rid of that loop: note that non-block do constructs like this one are deleted by Fortran 2015.